# Passing params from views to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a login form view for my rails app.

**Login form code -**

```
<h1>Log In</h1>
<%= form_tag dashboard_path do %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :phone %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= form tag sign_in_path do %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Log In"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So what I am trying here is that the submit button redirects to controller#action (sign_in_path) with `phone` and `password` as params that I entered in login page.

This login code is copied as I have zero html/angular knowledge also I am using jbuilder for rest of the views and not ERB.

**UPDATE** - 
`stdout` after first `GET` request

`Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-27 11:29:49 +0530
Processing by HulksController#new as HTML
  Rendering hulks/new.html.erb
  Rendered hulks/new.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 590)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1172)`

`stdout` after second `post` request, after hitting the login button.

`Started POST "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-11-27 11:30:03 +0530
Processing by HulksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Log In"}
App 11639 output: {"commit"=>"Log In", "controller"=>"hulks", "action"=>"create"}
App 11639 output: 
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 1273)`

Comment: Are you using `devise` for authentication?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Gabbar nope i am using JWT. But this is simply hardcoded, like i have saved phone and specific password in db and just testing it out. I want to know how can i pass params (phone and password in my view ) to controller method (url in seconf form tag)

Comment: @RajdeepSingh Provide `rake routes | grep dashboard`

Comment: @ray How can i pass params in my view to a controller. I am taking params under first form tag and the second form tags redirects it to the controller upon hitting the submit button but without the params.

Comment: @ray `dashboard GET     /dashboard(.:format)       hulks#new`

Comment: @ray this new method renders the above mentioned view where i enter `phone` and `password`. Now upon hitting the submit button i want the pass `phone` and `password` to controller method create for authentication. Upon hitting submit button, it rediercts to right controller method but without params.

Comment: You cannot use `<%= form_tag dashboard_path do %>` for `GET`. I will suggets to go through basic. Form is submitted for `PUT`, `POST` etc. actions with httb verbs. GET actiobs is used just to fetch data.

Comment: But it is working as expected, also i have ended the first `form tag` before the `post form tag`.

Comment: Why do you have two `form_tag`s? With two paths?

Comment: @jvillian Yes. The flow is when i hit `/dashboard` it opens up a login page and i enter the details and when i hit submit button it redirects to `/sign_in` where authetication logic is written and based on that logic it redirects to another (targeted url) or throws an error.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh please inspect web page (press f12) and check your html, you will understand , there will two form action , and your form is redirect according to you youe closest form action . :) please correct that.

Comment: @NeerajAmoli my que is how can i pass `params` in that view.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh brother  did you inspect web page , you need to remove <%= form_tag sign_in_path do %> this line , now rails engine itself send params value to that action which you defined above

Comment: @RajdeepSingh as you update question now write this line <%= form_tag sign_in_path do %> after h1 tag

Comment: @NeerajAmoli Done

Comment: @RajdeepSingh congrats :) please support answer .

Comment: @NeerajAmoli i have low reputation. Please tell me if there is any way i can do that, i will be glad.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh No issue brother , btw are you not able to press comments left upper traingular symbol :)

Comment: @NeerajAmoli You should post your solution as an answer, when the OP accepts the answer, you get 15, he gets 2. That's how the reputation increases.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh please write your original question , as you write your question code as a right answer:)

Comment: @NeerajAmoli I am the different Rajdeep you tagged lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `form_tag` in your example. Just change it to this:

```
 <h1>Log In</h1>
 <%= form_tag sign_in_path do %>
 <div class="field">
   <%= label_tag :phone %><br>
   <%= text_field_tag :phone %>
 </div>
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :password %><br>
  <%= password_field_tag :password %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
 <%= submit_tag "Log In"%>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this an answer? How is this different to the code already posted in the question?

Comment: i will re edit and post the original code to avoid confusion. Sorry